# Evaluating textbooks in math and physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

I’m currently interested in textbooks, especially the ones in math and physics that are used at the high school, undergraduate and graduate levels and, given the experience of the people on this website in using and teaching from these textbooks I’d appreciate your opinion on the following questions:

1. How do you choose which textbooks to use for your courses? (Which
   criteria do you employ? E.g. appropriate selection of exercises,
   etc.)
2. How have textbooks in your discipline(s) changed over the years
   (e.g. legibility, use of figures/examples, number of exercises
   given, how challenging they are, use of online resources,…)? (if
   they have changed at all) and do you find these changes beneficial
   or detrimental?
3. Do (and how) your criteria for choosing a textbook change when
   choosing an undergraduate or graduate textbook?

I welcome all of your comments regarding these and other questions related that you may deem relevant.

Thank you all for your time.

**NOTE:** I know that separate questions should be asked separately but these three are so closely related that it seems to make more sense to ask them together, since they all concern the single topic of the evaluation of textbooks.

Comment: This is a question about teaching physics rather than physics. It might be worth migrating it to the [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm attempting to answer the first question of yours.

In high school more importance is given to problem-solving and as we move on to UG and to PG the importance shifts from problem-solving to *understanding*. In today's time people think that *hard exercises makes a book good*, but I'm of opposite view point I think that the conceptual understanding is more important than to be able to solve problems created by *someone else's* mind and not by the nature. But to succeed in a course I cannot neglect the exams. Therefore, I always go for two kinds of book for surviving a course, one book focuses on problem-solving and the second one on the *elegant* conceptual understanding, for example if I were to choose books for freshman course in Physics then I will go for some recent books for problems and for the conceptual understanding I will use **The Feynman Lectures on Physics**.